# Split by digit and keep that digit in the results

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string that I want to split by digit. The problem is the separator should be kept in the results array.

```
'A1B2C'.split(/\d/);
// ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I'm getting letters only while I expect digits too, something like `['A', '1', 'B', '2', 'C']`.

Comment: Try: `let s = 'A1BB2C'.split(/(\d)/);` Which uses the `()` as a capture group.

Comment: What String are you starting with?

Comment: It would help you get a better answer if you gave a string that doesn't just split on each letter. I assume you want a string like `A1BB2C` to split with the `BB` together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting a capture group around the regexp tells `split()` to keep the delimiters in the result.

```js
console.log('A1B2C'.split(/(\d+)/));
```

Note that if the string begins or ends with a digit, this will result in an extra empty element before/after it:

```js
console.log('5A1B2C6'.split(/(\d+)/));
```

If this is a problem, you can filter them out.

```js
console.log('5A1B2C6'.split(/(\d+)/).filter(s => s != ""));
```

Comment: This is nice, but should probably check for the case when the string starts with a digit to avoid the empty string.

Comment: Thanks so much @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) instead and take connected same items.

```js
console.log('A1BB222C'.match(/\D+|\d+/g));
```

Comment: this solution will not work with this value 'A1BB2C'

Comment: @AhmedYousif, now it does.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use split. This should work

```js
"a1b2c3".split('');
```

Comment: this solution will not work with this value 'A1BB2C'